# PowerShell Foreach-Object {$_.Name} returns each letter of folder name when folder list is 1

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list the names of folders within a folder, and fill an array with them. It seems to be working fine when the list of folders is greater than 1, however when it is 1, it is filling my array with each letter of the folder.

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem $rootfolder | 
   Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
   Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

So when `$rootfolder` path has multiple subfolders, `$arr` is filled with the name of each one.

When `$rootfolder` has a single subfolder, `$arr` is filled with each letter of that subfolder name.

Comment: I can't repro your issue. Is that the complete code? Also, you can write the last line as `Select-Object Name`

Comment: Which PS version are you using?

Comment: i'm running version 5, but i'd like it to be backward compatible if possible

Comment: What do you do with the array after that bit of code?

Comment: `$arr = @( ... )`. *however when it is 1, it is filling my array with each letter of the folder* — when it is 1, it does not create array and you indexing string not array.

Comment: oops, it looks like i pasted the wrong code. i'm using :
`$arr = Get-ChildItem $p4root | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}`
Updated the main question to reflect this, sorry!

Comment: Ok then @PetSerAl is right. Using `Foreach-object` will cause this. Use `Select-object -expandproperty name` instead and that should work. Also, please edit the question to rectify the code, in case someone else comes across it.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm daft. Use a combination of what I said and what @PetSerAl said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the actual code causing the issue was this:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem $p4root | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Partly based on @PetSerAl's comment, a solution to get similar, but functioning, output would be this:

```
$arr = @(Get-ChildItem $p4root | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Select-object -expandproperty name)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue!